# PayFort SDK Integration in iOS (Objective C)

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, payfort

I want to integrate Payfort payment gateway in my app and i cant seem to understand the guidelines provided by the sdk... if possible, can anyone provide the steps? to generate the sdk token/signature and the bill? thanks in advance.

Comment: i am in the same route :( but i have implemented each and every thing what i giving me the issue is ... it is not showing any default card for or account info

Comment: https://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2017/05/ios-payfort-payment-gateway-integration.html

Comment: use this link for reference....let me knw if ur stuck again...